# How to parse a list within a table in Snowflake using SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, flatten

So I have a table as such:

```
ID   VALUE               KEY    DATE        USER
001  ["a"]               group1 2021-01-01  212
002  []                  group2 2021-01-01  212
003  ["a","c"]           group1 2021-01-02  212
004  ["apple", "pear"]   group3 2021-01-02  211
```

I would like to restructure this data so that each list element becomes its own row. If `VALUE` is an empty list, the expectation is it does not appear in the final dataset.

Final result should be:

```
ID   VALUE   KEY    DATE        USER
001  "a"     group1 2021-01-01  212
003  "a"     group1 2021-01-02  212
003  "c"     group1 2021-01-02  212
004  "apple" group3 2021-01-02  211
004  "pear"  group3 2021-01-02  211
```

I think using `FLATTEN()` in Snowflake should work here but I cant seem to get it.

Comment: Is the VALUE column an array or a string?

Comment: `VARCHAR(16777216)` aka string

Comment: Okay. I'll update my answer unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: nice  yeah yours was close; what was the function for string to table?

Comment: The previous answer worked if the VALUE column is defined as an array. The split_to_table table function works better for turning delimited strings into rows.

Comment: The query you wrote I was able to fix to make it work for a string, using split_to_table. Feel free to add the original answer and I will up vote my brother

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the FLATTEN version:

```
SELECT 
  ID, f.VALUE, t.KEY, DATE, USER
FROM
test t, table(
  FLATTEN(
    INPUT => STRTOK_TO_ARRAY(value, '[], "')
  )
) f;
```

Answer (score 1):

The nested replace functions simply remove the square brackets so the split_to_table table function can do its thing.

```
select T1.ID, V1."VALUE", T1.KEY, T1."DATE", T1."USER"
from TABLE1 T1, table(split_to_table(replace(replace(VALUE, '[', ''), ']', ''), ',')) V1
where V1."VALUE" <> ''
;
```